# Switch between three (3) audio devices using autohotkey (AHK)

Tags: autohotkey

just found out about AHK.
I have three audio devices (Speakers, Headphones, TV)

[image]

Cant figure out the AHK syntax to switch between them with one key, lets say F2.
This tiny script toggles between two devices, but I need to switch between three.

```
F2::
if (toggle := !toggle) 
{ 
    run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice "tv"
} 
else 
{ 
    run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice "headphones"
}
return
```

So I was thinking about something like this, where **device** is a variable to hold audio device name:

```
device = "Speakers"
F2::
if (device = "Speakers") device = "TV"
else if (device = "TV") device = "Headphones"
else if (device = "Headphones") device = "Speakers"
run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice device
return
```

Just cant make this as valid AHK script.
Any help is appreciated
P.S. nircmd utility allows to set audio device from command line

Thanks.

**UPD** Updated to this, but %device% is empty for unknown reason.
Followed the manual (https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm), should work, but it doesnt :(

[image]

**UPD2** As @Blauhim suggested, I had another key binding before it with return statement. Once I moved the script to the top, it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: "Any help is appreciated" - https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
device := "Speakers" ; alternative: device = Speakers
F2::
if (device = "Speakers") 
    device := "TV" ; had to be on the next line
else if (device = "TV") 
    device := "Headphones" ; had to be on the next line
else if (device = "Headphones") 
    device := "Speakers" ; had to be on the next line
run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice %device%
return
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to move device := after IF to the next line to make it work
However %device% is empty when it gets to: run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice %device%

Comment: @monstro It works for me, the msgbox shows the proper value. --> `device := "Speakers"` has to be in the auto-execution section of your script, meaning: there must be NO `return` before it (and thus also no hotkey, hotstring or similar). See https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto for details

Comment: @Blauhim Yes, you are absolutely right! I had another key binding before it with return statement. Once I move the script to the top, it worked like a charm. Thank you.